# Where shoud I call Google map methods in my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using redux to manage my app state,and using Google map(or other map) to show my data.

I have a very complex UI and want to manage it with redux. But I have a question below:

1. I have two components A and B, they are in separate parts, A is a button , B is a component with Google map in it as a inner property called "map"
2. When Click A ,I want to trigger `map.panBy(-10,-20)`, the result is that center will be changed, but by executing `panBy` there is an animation, in this case `(-10, -20)` is not the result, it's just offset, so save it(offset) on the store is not a good idea. What shoud I do?
3. `Solution I`: using redux data flow, dispatch an action like `{type:'panBy', payload: [-10, -20]}`, and when component B get the data, execute `map.panBy(-10,-20)`.  --> -10, -20 are temporary params, store them is weird.
4. `Solution II` : Eventbus, component A trigger event and component B subscribe it .
5. `Solution III`: Expose `map` to it's parent or to the `window` object. --> weird too...

So, is there a common solution to resolve this?

Can I use redux middleware? But middleware DONOT know the `map` either.

Comment: This is a really good question btw - well done.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly:

1. You have some data
2. You are going to display that data on a map.

What's a little unclear with your question - is whether the panBy parameters are data you are storing in your redux state.

It's a little bit odd that you *would* store those parameters in the redux state, because those are more actions that you do once, rather than objective data about a thing.

What I mean is - the kind of data I imagine you would store in state would be data like 'name', 'address', 'lat lng', data that is always going to look the same when you apply it. Whereas 'pan' data is going to be displayed differently each time you display it.

But in any case - if you are just displaying/applying whatever you have in your redux state - what I would do is:

1. Connect the redux state to the component via mapStateToProps
2. Implement componentDidUpdate, and if the mapData has updated, then apply all the relevant map methods.

But back to the panBy thing - I would suggest that instead of storing panBy parameters, you should be storing the map center and zoom level. That way, it will look the same everytime you apply it.

Alternatively, you could store the original center *and* the panBy parameters, and use that recalc the map each time.

ie. the redux state would like:

```
mapState: {

    center: {
     x: 100, 
     y: 200, 
    },
    panBy: {
     x: 10, 
     y: 0
    }    
}
```

and then in your `componentDidUpdate` you both recenter it - and apply the pan, something like:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.mapState !== prevProps.mapState) {
         const {mapState} = this.props.mapState; 
         Map.center(mapState.center); 
         Map.panBy(mapState.panBy); 
    }
}
```

The disadvantage with this - is that you are redundantly recentering the map each time, and depending on how the API works, it might look bad.

I do think the better solution, is to manually recalculate the center yourself - as Spark.Bao suggests.

Comment: Yes,  I should store the map center(lat, lng), not x,y,  so I don't want to put this in my redux state. 
[panBy](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.panBy)

But by using redux, I don't know if there is a way to call map.xxx method, reducer donot know there is something called "map".

Comment: @WangYuJing you would call the map methods inside your React component, in the componentDidUpdate function. And also in the constructor, if the data already exists when your component mounts.  Or look at using [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

Comment: Assuming there are two components, A is a component with Google map instance "map", B is a button trigger the map "panBy  -10, -20", so how should B trigger this behavior? B don't know there is a map, I want a common solution like: 1, you can trigger this using redux, but to me -10,-20 is useless.  2, you can use Eventbus, B trigger a event,  A receive the message and do the panBy action. 3,...

So, which is the right way?

Comment: @WangYuJing -Ok, I getchu, please update your question to say that you have a seperate control panel object.

Answer (score 1):

agree with @dwjohnston, you should save the state likes center and zoom in the redux store, your map should have an initial center at least, right, that value should be your initial state, for example:

```
const initialState = {
  center: {
    lat: 100,
    lng: 100
  },
  zoom: ...
}

function mapOptions(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    ...
  }
}
```

after dispatching the action, the reducer should modify the state according to the payload (the action should be `{type: "panBy", payload: [-10, -20]}`):

```
function mapOptions(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "panBy":
      const offset = action.payload
      return {
        ...state,
        center: {
          lat: state.center.lat + offset[0],
          lng: state.center.lng + offset[1]
        }
      } 
  }
}
```

then your component B should update the map center by the new state.

---

don't know how far the A component and B component separate, if A component is inside B component, you call use callback from A until it reaches B, for example:

```
class A extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <button onClick={()=>this.props.moveMap(-10, -20)}>Move</button>
  }
}

class B extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }

  handleMoveMap = (offsetLng, offsetLat) => {
    this.map.panBy(offsetLng, offsetLat)
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <div id="map"/>
      <A moveMap={this.handleMoveMap}/>
    </div>
  }
}
```

else you can choose `Solution III`, it works and more convenient, but it is not React pattern (data drive UI), it is jQuery pattern (manually operate DOM). (sometimes I use jQuery pattern in my React project as well).

in React and Redux thinking, you should put the shared data by different components in the redux store.

Comment: Thank U. but modify center directly maybe a bad idea if panBy triggers an animation. I'm finding a way that can call the panBy method(trigger the animation) , save center(not save offset).

Comment: @WangYuJing - in asking your question it might have been helpful if you included why you it's important to call the panBy method (because it triggers an animation).

Comment: @dwjohnston OK, there are lots of methods in google map api or other map apis, like flyTo, panBy, the result is map center will be changed, but in the progress there are animations. And I don't want save the params to the store.

Comment: A and B are not parent and child, and I want clear and strict code coz A or C or D components are written by different guys. So I need a pattern to solve this.

Comment: got it, so putting it in the redux store is the best choice if you want to follow the react and redux pattern strictly, though it is truly boring and not convenient.